# GMAIL: Send one email with multiple addresses or sending multiple emails. Which one is better?

Tags: java, smtp, gmail, jms

My web app using JMS to send mail via GMAIL as my SMTP server. I need to send out email to every people in my group (20 - 50 people), does GMAIL allow to send this many email in short amount of time? And if so, can I get around with either sending one email with multiple addesses or sending multiple email with one address.

Comment: I've used Delphi and Indy to send about 20 emails from Gmail with about 5 seconds break between each without a problem.  I imagine it would be easier with one email and x amount of BCC, though.

Comment: Emphasis on BCC, don't put everyone into the recipients field.

Comment: why use BCC instead of recipients if the data including recipient list is not sensitive? sounds like there's some additional hidden magic that has not been explained.

Comment: @crowne: no hidden magic here. Just want to make sure :D

Comment: @Crowne: unless the recipients can be expected to know each other, you use the BCC so that your distribution list isn't known, and you don't provide valid email addresses to potential harvesters.  You also don't want a customer to "reply-all" with a rant about how your product sucks to the 200 other people on your email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about this:

If you send one email, the mail server does the work sending a copy to each recipient.

If you send 20 emails, your code does all the work, sending 20 copies over the network to the email server.

You may want to use `bcc:` for the recipients if you don't want every recipient to see the address of every other.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason you would want to send multiple messages is if you want to customize the message, such as

```
Hello <username> 

blah blah blah
```

Comment: I always just use "Dear Friend, I represent the estate of the exiled Prince Mutatu ... " :-D